# Como filtrar objeto

Tags: javascript

Quero simplesmente filtrar os alunos com notas acima ou igual a 7 e mostrar no `console.log`

```
const pessoa = (nome, idade, nota) =>{
    return {
        nome,
        idade,
        nota,
    }
}

const listalunos = [
 {aluno1: pessoa("maria", 20, 7)},
 {aluno2: pessoa("joao", 23, 5)},
 {aluno3: pessoa("pedro", 15, 10)},
 {aluno4: pessoa("eduardo", 24, 9)},
]


const notas = listalunos.filter(function(x){
    return x >= 7
})

console.log(listalunos.length)
console.log(listalunos.nota)
console.log(notas)
```

Comment: Poderia explicar por que a sua lista é uma lista de objetos onde cada objeto define uma chave diferente para guardar o objeto `pessoa`? Por que não é apenas uma lista de pessoas?

Comment: Essa definição da lista de alunos não tem sentido, e acaba complicando algo simples, que podia ser apenas `const notas = listalunos.filter(x => x.nota >= 7)`, desde que fosse definido como `const listalunos = [pessoa("maria", 20, 7), pessoa("joao", 23, 5), etc]; `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não vejo sentido em definir uma lista de objetos com as chaves `aluno1`, `aluno2`, `aluno3`, etc, justamente porque você não terá controle direto sobre qual chave ter que acessar em cada objeto.

Por exemplo, se eu precisar o nome do aluno na posição 5 da lista, como faria?

```
listalunos[5][???].nome
```

Ah, mas se é na posição 5, deve ser `aluno5`, então `listalunos[5]["aluno5"].nome`, mas e se não for? E se o objeto com "aluno5" nem estar mais na lista?

Você não precisa dessa chave, basta criar uma lista de pessoas:

```js
const pessoa = (nome, idade, nota) =>{
    return {
        nome,
        idade,
        nota,
    }
}

const alunos = [
  pessoa("maria", 20, 7),
  pessoa("joao", 23, 5),
  pessoa("pedro", 15, 10),
  pessoa("eduardo", 24, 9),
]
```

E com isso fazer o filtro que deseja fica trivial:

```
const aprovados = alunos.filter(aluno => aluno.nota >= 7)
```

Não precisa de todo o esforço para resolver um problema que você mesmo inseriu.

```js
const pessoa = (nome, idade, nota) =>{
    return {
        nome,
        idade,
        nota,
    }
}

const alunos = [
  pessoa("maria", 20, 7),
  pessoa("joao", 23, 5),
  pessoa("pedro", 15, 10),
  pessoa("eduardo", 24, 9),
]

const aprovados = alunos.filter(aluno => aluno.nota >= 7)

console.log(aprovados)
```

Answer (score 3):

O `x` no seu filtro retorna cada objeto do `listalunos`, então não tem como saber se a nota dentro do objeto é maior ou igual a 7 apenas com `x >= 7`.

Você tem que acessar a chave `nota` dentro de cada objeto no `x`. Pode fazer isso usando `Object.keys(x)`. Irá retornar arrays com os nomes dos objetos em `x`:

```
['aluno1']
['aluno2']
['aluno3']
...
```

Então basta pegar o primeiro e único índice de cada array:

```
Object.keys(x)[0]
```

E aplicar no filtro acessando a chave `nota` dentro de cada objeto de `x`:

```
return x[Object.keys(x)[0]].nota >= 7
```

Exemplo:

```js
const pessoa = (nome, idade, nota) =>{ return { nome, idade, nota, } }

const listalunos = [ {aluno1: pessoa("maria", 20, 7)}, {aluno2: pessoa("joao", 23, 5)}, {aluno3: pessoa("pedro", 15, 10)}, {aluno4: pessoa("eduardo", 24, 9)}, ]

const notas = listalunos.filter(function(x){ return x[Object.keys(x)[0]].nota >= 7 })

console.log(notas)
```

Uma outra forma seria, caso os nomes dos objetos sejam na sequência (aluno1, aluno2, aluno3 etc...) é pegar o segundo argumento do filter que retorna o índice dos objetos (começando do 0), somar +1 e concatenar com o "aluno":

```js
const pessoa = (nome, idade, nota) =>{ return { nome, idade, nota, } }

const listalunos = [ {aluno1: pessoa("maria", 20, 7)}, {aluno2: pessoa("joao", 23, 5)}, {aluno3: pessoa("pedro", 15, 10)}, {aluno4: pessoa("eduardo", 24, 9)}, ]

const notas = listalunos.filter(function(x,i){ return x["aluno"+ (i+1)].nota >= 7 })

console.log(notas)
```